nuxt3 couldnt import css files
enter image description heremy css file is under assets and when i try to  use it as global in nuxt.config.ts couldnt get accept how do i fix this
I'm currently working on a Nuxt 3 application and have encountered several issues during startup. Despite adhering closely to the Nuxt 3 documentation and ensuring my development environment meets all prerequisites, I've been plagued by persistent errors. Specifically, when attempting to launch the application with npm run dev, I encounter a ParseError targeting my nuxt.config.ts file, indicating an unexpected token and failing to resolve an import. Additionally, there's an error related to a failed import resolution for a CSS file located in the assets directory. I've meticulously reviewed my nuxt.config.ts for syntax errors and confirmed that all dependencies are correctly installed, yet these issues persist. I'm seeking guidance on resolving these errors.
I've attempted to rectify the issues by reinstalling packages and recreating the problematic files, yet these efforts have not yielded the desired outcome. Despite meticulous attention to detail and adherence to Nuxt 3's documentation, I continue to face persistent errors upon attempting to launch the application with npm run dev. These errors primarily revolve around a ParseError within my nuxt.config.ts file, signaling an unexpected token and import resolution failure, alongside issues with importing a CSS file from the assets directory. Even after ensuring the correctness of my nuxt.config.ts syntax and verifying the installation of all necessary dependencies, the underlying problems remain unresolved.
